# How to Re Render App Components after Contact form Submit?

Tags: php, reactjs, react-native

**Hello Developer** :

I have two components App and ContactForm (two are in the same js files).
ContactForm action to submit data into database
and App action to display Data in table View using Datatable

The issue is after contact form submission can not table data updated (re-render)

**App.js file look like as** :

```
class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.get_data();
  }
  get_data() {
    const url = 'api/contacts.php'
    axios.get(url).then(response => response.data)
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({ contacts: data })
      console.log(this.state.contacts)
    })
  }

  state = {
    contacts: []
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
      <DataTable title="Contact Details" columns={columns} data={this.state.contacts} pagination = {true} paginationPerPage = {5} selectableRows onRowSelected={this.handleChange} striped />
      <ContactForm />

      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

class ContactForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    country: '',
    city: '',
    job: '',
    f_error: '',
  }

  handleFormSubmit( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let name = this.state.name;
    let email = this.state.email;
    let city = this.state.city;
    let country = this.state.country;
    let job = this.state.job;

    if(name === ''){
      this.setState({f_error: 'Name can not be blank'});
    } else if(email === ''){
      this.setState({f_error: 'Email can not be blank'});
    } else if(!email.match(/^([\w.%+-]+)@([\w-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})$/i)){
      this.setState({f_error: 'Email is invalid'});
    } else if(city === ''){
      this.setState({f_error: 'City can not be blank'});
    } else if(country === ''){
      this.setState({f_error: 'Country can not be blank'});
    } else if(job === ''){
      this.setState({f_error: 'Job can not be blank'});
    } else{

      this.setState({f_error: ''});

      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('name', name)
      formData.append('email', email)
      formData.append('city', city)
      formData.append('country', country)
      formData.append('job', job)

      axios.post('api/contacts.php', formData)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        this.setState({ contacts:res.data });
      });
    }
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <form>
      <p className="error">{this.state.f_error}</p>
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" value={this.state.name}
      onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}/>
      <br/>
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" value={this.state.email}
      onChange={e => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}/>
      <br/>
      <label>Country</label>
      <input type="text" name="country" value={this.state.country}
      onChange={e => this.setState({ country: e.target.value })}/>
      <br/>
      <label>City</label>
      <input type="text" name="city" value={this.state.city}
      onChange={e => this.setState({ city: e.target.value })}/>
      <br/>
      <label>Job</label>
      <input type="text" name="job" value={this.state.job}
      onChange={e => this.setState({ job: e.target.value })}/>
      <br/><br/>
      <input type="submit" onClick={e => this.handleFormSubmit(e)} value="Create Contact" />
      </form>);
    }
  }

  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

  export default App;
```

can you please anyone help with this issue.
In Advance Thanks

Comment: please use handleFormSubmit in parent component and pass function to child so that you could save response in parent state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first move the handleFormSubmit method to the App component, you can then pass this as props down to the child component and call that when the form is submitted.

Once you have done this, re-call the get_data function after form has submitted, this will update the data in the component and cause a re-render which will refresh the data on the page. You shouldn't have the state update in the .then of the submission function. Submit the data to the back-end, then re-call the get_data method, that way you can be certain that data which is rendering on the front-end is present on the back-end. The code is this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.get_data();
  }
  get_data() {
    const url = 'api/contacts.php'
    axios.get(url).then(response => response.data)
  .then((data) => {
      this.setState({ contacts: data })
      console.log(this.state.contacts)
    })
  };

  handleFormSubmit( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let name = this.state.name;
    let email = this.state.email;
    let city = this.state.city;
    let country = this.state.country;
    let job = this.state.job;

    if(name === ''){
      this.setState({f_error: 'Name can not be blank'});
    } else if(email === ''){
      this.setState({f_error: 'Email can not be blank'});
    } else if(!email.match(/^([\w.%+-]+)@([\w-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})$/i)){
      this.setState({f_error: 'Email is invalid'});
    } else if(city === ''){
      this.setState({f_error: 'City can not be blank'});
    } else if(country === ''){
      this.setState({f_error: 'Country can not be blank'});
    } else if(job === ''){
      this.setState({f_error: 'Job can not be blank'});
    } else{

      this.setState({f_error: ''});

      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('name', name)
      formData.append('email', email)
      formData.append('city', city)
      formData.append('country', country)
      formData.append('job', job)

      axios.post('api/contacts.php', formData)
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data);
            this.get_data()
          });
    }
  }


  state = {
    contacts: []
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
        <DataTable title="Contact Details" columns={columns} data={this.state.contacts} pagination = {true} paginationPerPage = {5} selectableRows onRowSelected={this.handleChange} striped />
    <ContactForm handleFormSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}/>

    </React.Fragment>
  );
  }
}

class ContactForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    country: '',
    city: '',
    job: '',
    f_error: '',
  }


  render(){
    return (
        <form>
        <p className="error">{this.state.f_error}</p>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value={this.state.name}
    onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}/>
    <br/>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" value={this.state.email}
    onChange={e => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}/>
    <br/>
    <label>Country</label>
    <input type="text" name="country" value={this.state.country}
    onChange={e => this.setState({ country: e.target.value })}/>
    <br/>
    <label>City</label>
    <input type="text" name="city" value={this.state.city}
    onChange={e => this.setState({ city: e.target.value })}/>
    <br/>
    <label>Job</label>
    <input type="text" name="job" value={this.state.job}
    onChange={e => this.setState({ job: e.target.value })}/>
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" onClick={e => this.props.handleFormSubmit(e)} value="Create Contact" />
        </form>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

export default App;
```

Comment: Got this error : Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.get_data is not a function

Comment: @BhAvikGajjar Apologies, I hadn't realised that these were seperate components, I will update my original answer.

Comment: No Problem lek.

Comment: @BhAvikGajjar updated :) I did this in a text editor with no linting, so you may need to double check the syntax.

Comment: @BhAvikGajjar Make sure you have my latest edit, I had to edit a couple of times. Last updated literally just now; make sure you have that version.

Comment: Thanks a lot It's working with simple table 
but not working with datatable.

Comment: Just either update datatable to use the same onSubmit action as the simple table, or update dataTable's onSubmit method to have the same call to the get_data method. You haven't posted the code to DataTable's `this.handleChange`, so I can't see what it is doing.

Also, please can you mark my solution as the correct one if it works for you please :)